# Error al referenciar un objeto que se encuentra ubicado en otro controlador "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: javafx, controller

Lo que quiero, es que desde el segundo controlador (ControllerScreen1), poder modificar el texto del botón que se encuentra en el otro controlador (ControllerDocument). Muchas gracias
Acá esta el código que estoy utilizando:

```
package sample;
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource( "/sample/multiple_fxml_loading/FXMLDocument.fxml" ));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Este es el fxml Principal
FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.multiple_fxml_loading.ControllerDocument">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="mainPane" >
         <left>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" style="-fx-background-color: #AAABBB;" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="button1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton1" text="Button1">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="20.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="button2"  mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton2" text="Button2" />
               </children>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </VBox>
         </left>
         <center>
            <Pane fx:id="pane" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
         <bottom>
            <TextField fx:id="textFieldMenuContec" text="Menú Contectual" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </bottom>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Su Controlador:

```
package sample.multiple_fxml_loading;
   
public class ControllerDocument implements Initializable {
    @FXML private BorderPane mainPane;    
    @FXML public Button button1, button2;    
    private static Pane paneView1 = null;
    @FXML void handleButton1(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println( "Clic en el Boton 1" );
            ControllerMultipleDocument controllerMultipleDocument = new ControllerMultipleDocument();
            Pane paneView = controllerMultipleDocument.getPage( "screen1" );
            paneView1 = controllerMultipleDocument.getPage( "screen1" );
            mainPane.setCenter( paneView );
            variableBooleana = false;
    }
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }       
}
```

Segundo Archivo fxml, screen1.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: #FF5733;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.multiple_fxml_loading.ControllerScreen1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="labelPantalla" text="Pantalla 1" />
      <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" text="Button" />
      <JFXTextField fx:id=""  />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Su Controlador:

```
package sample.multiple_fxml_loading;
   
public class ControllerScreen1<JFXTextField> {    
    @FXML private Label labelPantalla;   
    @FXML private Button button;    
    @FXML private JFXTextField textField;    
    @FXML private ControllerDocument controllerDocument;

    @FXML
    void handleButton(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println( "Clic : " + labelPantalla.getText() );
        controllerDocument.button1.setText("XXX");    
    }
}
```

Y aca el error que me arroja:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.multiple_fxml_loading.ControllerScreen1.handleButton(ControllerScreen1.java:18)
... 58 more

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Dónde inicializas el campo `controllerDocument` de la clase `ControllerScreen1`??

Comment: En el método "initialize" de la clase "ControllerScreen1", me falto colocar en la clase que ella implementa "Initializable"